# How to Use URL dispatcher to get clickable link to list contents of my page DJANGO

Tags: python, django, templates, url

I want to make a list of items showing on my index.html page to be clickable, I used the url dynamic reverse technique but i keep getting this error.

Please guide me on what I may be doing wrong.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%25%20url%20'entrypage'%20entry%20%25
Using the URLconf defined in wiki.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='index']
wiki/<str:title> [name='entrypage']
The current path, {% url 'entrypage' entry %, didn’t match any of these.
```

URLS.PY

```
app_name = "encyclopedia"

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:title>", views.entry_page, name='entrypage'),
]
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <li>
            <a href="{% url 'entrypage' entry %">{{ entry }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

VIEWS.PY

```
def entry_page(request, title):
    title = util.get_entry(title)
    if title:
        content = markdown2.markdown(title)
        context = {
            "title": title,
            "content": content,
        }

       return render(request, "encyclopedia/entrypage.html", context) 
    else:
       return render(request, "encyclopedia/errorpage.html")
```

What am i doing wrong please. I'm a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops, you're missing the closing curly bracket of the url template tag

```
<a href="{% url 'entrypage' entry %}">{{ entry }}</a>
```

You may also need to pass through the title rather than the entry instance because that's what entry_page uses for the look up.

```
<a href="{% url 'entrypage' entry.title %}">{{ entry }}</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked for me. Whoosh, rookie mistake. Have a great day, everyday.

Comment: Every django dev has made this mistake, no worries.